# Image stored in express not displayed in React img component

Tags: reactjs, express

**Backend**

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static("./server/uploads"));

index.js
server
---uploads
------16562777154317mbc3jbenz.png
```

[Backend folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZOa.png)

I want to access it by URL in chrome: http://localhost:4500/uploads/16562777154317mbc3jbenz.png
It works.

[Image opens in the web browser by URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpTJh.png)

**Frontend**

```
<img src="http://localhost:4500/uploads/16562777154317mbc3jbenz.png" alt="Test" style="height: 200px; object-fit: cover;">
```

The image does not display.

[Image does not display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxgbr.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @nedoder Check I have updated my description, the image does not display.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxgbr.png

Comment: I understood that, but what error do you get, cors or not found, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes at back-end

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Comment: This opens up the door for everyone if you're using `*` for Origin, but I'm also thinking about CORS for OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

add this on img component, since they are two different sources

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```